# assigning a data attribute to a model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

In my markup I have:

```
<div class="sli1"
     data-values="10, 20, 30, 40,50, 60, 70"
```

Is there anyway I can bind the data-values to be a model I can reuse with angular, looking through ng-bind I can't figure out how I'd be able to do this.

Comment: If you can't modify the template, no, it's impossible.

Comment: @Poiro Can you edit the attribute name where the values are written?

Comment: yeah the attribute name is not an issue, simply the values come across in there as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="sli1" data-values="{{ dataValues.join(',') }}">The div tab</div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.dataValues = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];
    });
</script>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: the values come inside the data-values="" so I wouldn't be able to place them down into $scope.dataValues right?

Comment: Yes, value inside "data-values" attributes is for display. The actually underlying data is $scope.dataValues, you will process it.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-list` directive will allow you to do this thing, only you need to use `[]` array instead of string.

**Markup**

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="test=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]">
  <input ng-model="test" ng-list="," />
</body>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MmQk7nL7mObyrm3WES2v?p=preview)